# Assign a variable in rails with the optionally presented array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables

How could variable be assigned in the easy and straightforward way in this case:

```
interface = reply[:user][:interface][:data][0][:value].presence || 'simple'
```

If the array key `reply[:user][:interface]` exists - I have the whole data chain (in this case) but if it doesn't - I get the `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. In general I want a method to assign default if any of the keys in a path doesn't exists. Now I do it like:

```
a = b[:asd][:qwe] rescue 5
```

which works but doesn't look like a proper way.

Comment: Hm.. so the best way to handle this is not to have variable structures from the API if it possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with calling `rescue` like that is that it traps more errors than just the one you want, and so can hide problems. So the "proper way" is to rescue on only the error you expect:

```
begin
   reply[:user][:interface][:data][0][:value].presence || 'simple'
rescue NoMethodError
  'simple'
end
```

Comment: even this may produce unintended results if `presence` or `reply` itself is undefined. hard to be concise and correct here.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface = [:user, :interface, :data, 0, :value]
.inject(reply){|h, k| h = h.fetch(k, {})}
.presence ||
'simple'
```

Comment: nice solution, but only works if the methods have same-type return value (hash), can be improved as .inject(reply){|h, k| h.nil? ? h : h[k] } .

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a misconception in your code.

You shouldn't work directly on `reply[:user][:interface][:data][0][:value]` if `[:interface]` could be missing but more something like

```
reply[:user].has_key?(:interface) && reply[:user][:interface][:data][0][:value]
```

And if on top of that, `[:data]` or `[:data][0]` or `[:data][0][:value]` can be missing, then you should make some verification **before** using all these data.

Comment: In general I have structures where I couldn't predict which key would be missed. And I have a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

one generic pattern for 'guarded method chaining' is to use is https://github.com/raganwald/andand
with this you could write (credit sawa):

```
interface = [:user, :interface, :data, 0, :value]
.inject(reply){|h, k| h.andand[k] } || 'simple'
```

but honestly it often better style to be explicit